# Вычислить разницу между датами

Tags: mysql, дата

Есть таблица Mysql, в ней столбец "data" с типом datetime.
Нужно взять текущую дату и время и посчитать разницу с табличным значением и вывести результат в формате dd-hh-mm

```
SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(now())-UNIX_TIMESTAMP(users.data)) from users where UserId=999929921;
```

пробовал вот так, все работает до тех пор, пока разница между датами не больше 1 дня, далее выводится ошибка, так как `SEC_TO_TIME` работает в интервале 24 часов к сожалению.
Собственно вопрос, как правильно написать запрос?

Comment: есть много готовых diff-функций, например https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff

Comment: ни одна функция по приведенной вами ссылке не делает то,о чем я спрашивал

Comment: готовых явно нет. вопрос в том, можете ли вы выполнить некоторые преобразования на стороне клиента. Потому что есть timediff которая дает часы (больше 24) минуты секунды. Вот часы превращать в дни на стороне клиента было бы гораздо проще, чем в MySQL. Собственно ничего сложного нет, всего то делить на 24 и отдельно брать остаток от деления на 24, но очень громоздко это выходит

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно например как нибудь так:

```
concat(lpad(floor((@h:=time_format(@tm:=timediff(now(), users.data), '%H'))/24), 2, '0'),
       '-',
       lpad(@h % 24, 2, '0'),
       '-',
       time_format(@tm, '%i'))
```

Вопрос в том, а стоит ли делать такие громоздкие конструкции в SQL, если на клиенте обычно гораздо больше средств для форматирования времени.

Пример на [SQLFiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ccce1e/2)

Comment: Mike что это за код?воркбенч и intellej ругаются на него.код пишется на java,там чтобы все это прописать и посчтиить нужно городить еще простыню кода.гораздо проще это сделать в sql запросе.нужно только найти специалиста ,который понимает как

Comment: @Алексеевстанислав Обычный MySQL код. Добавил рабочий пример

Comment: Mike,Огромное спасибо все заработало наконец то.

Comment: Mike,вы не знаете случаем как добавить локальное время в таблицу?в слайет это была функция Now,Localtime.В mysql эти функции возвращают GMT время и влияет ли как то локация самой базы?потому что база находится как раз таки в англии,а  я в мск -чье локальное время запишет база свое или клиентское?

Comment: @Алексеевстанислав Она запишет в таблицу локальное время клиента (временная зона задается в настройках сессии `@@session.time_zone`). Но datetime хранит абсолютное значение, после того как время туда записано оно будет иметь одинаковое значение вне зависимости от настроек зоны.

Comment: это мне как раз и нужно,чтобы время всегда было московское.Единственный нюанс задавать временную зону мне придется каждый раз когда я провожу манипуляции со временем?

Comment: @Алексеевстанислав Ставьте сразу при подключении к БД

Comment: толи лыжи не едут не знаю,толи mysql это полнейший шлак.запустил программу вылезло миллиард ошибок,русские буквы не читает,не пишет,локальную дату то пишет то нет.так как постоянно теряется соединение с базой,это вообще нормальная ситуация?отсылаешь запрос -пишет извините пакет не ушел -соединение прервано..сама база находится на heroku .время записывает.но его не видит -пишет в ответе на запрос нулл...

Comment: @Алексеевстанислав С русскими надо не забыть опять же на соединение выставить правильные настройки локали. Соединения которыми пользуются хотя бы раз в минуту могут жить без разрыва годами. Через раз то писать то нет при правильно сделанной программе оно не может. Так же как и возвращать null при правильно записанной дате (при неправильно записанной может, MySQL может замалчивать ошибки и тихо писать null если формат даты например неправильный был).

Answer (score 2):

Можно получить diff в секундах и делением с округлением в меньшую сторону построить нужную дату. Вот пример без форматирования и только для дней-часов. Остальное, думаю, не сложно дописать, если решение устроит.

```
SELECT
    t.total_seconds,
    t.total_days,
    FLOOR((t.total_seconds - (t.total_days * 24 * 60 * 60)) / (60 * 60)) AS total_hours
FROM (
    SELECT
        t.total_seconds,
        FLOOR(t.total_seconds / (24 * 60 * 60)) AS total_days
    FROM (
        SELECT TIME_TO_SEC(
            TIMEDIFF("2018-12-25 18:40:00", "2018-12-23 15:20:30")
        ) AS total_seconds
    ) t
) t
```

Вывод:

```
total_seconds total_days total_hours
       184770          2           3
```

Comment: lexx почти так ,но вместо дат у меня идут now()  и значение из таблицы users.data ( where userId=123123).далее нужен вывод ввиде обычного текста например 10 дней 2 часа 12 минут .так как все это передается в переменную джава типо string и отсылается клиенту в телеграм бот.как доработать ваш код чтобы он отвечал нужным критериям